generar tabla dinámica con los datos elegidos y exportarlos a excel
Hola a todos vengo de nuevo con esto para lo cual abro una nueva consulta, ya em ayudaron en este mismo foro a realizar un proyecto el cual consistía en ir armando la consulta MySQL con chekbox, por lo cual amablemente me orientaron a terminar algo en lo que me sentía un poco perdido.
ahora pido amablemente me orienten como hacer para que en la parte de la creación de la tabla para mostrar los resultados, se genere la tabla con los encabezados y sus datos respectivos. pues actualmente tengo una tabla estática y existe también una parte del código que al oprimir el botón debería generarme un Excel con los datos que allí se muestran, pero igual no se por que no me los exporta pues lo he hecho tal como me lo indica el tutorial de donde lo saque.
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contrasena");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,"bd");
$municipio=$_POST["municipio"];
if($municipio=="TODOS"){
$municc="";
}else{
$municc=" AND municipio='".$municipio."'";
}
$estad=$_POST["estadotrabajador"];
// este campo para la edad------------
$edad=$_POST["edad"];
if($edad=="si"){
    $consulty=" ,fecha_nacimiento
       , YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) AS anio_nacimiento
       , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_nacimiento, CURDATE()) edad ";
}else{
    $consulty="";
}
$Consulta = "SELECT ";
//Pregunto si ha sido enviado el formulario , en este caso si el arreglo POST presenta el indice enviar que no es mas que el nombre del botón del formulario
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    //Mantengo esta línea que tenias
    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
    //Almaceno la longitud del arreglo para comparar posteriormente y para tomarlo como referencia en el ciclo for a continuación
    $length = count($_POST["estados"]); 
    //Recorro el arreglo pasado por el formulario con los valores de los checkbox que fueron marcados
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
         $Consulta .= " ".$_POST["estados"][$i]." ".(($i == $length-1)?"":" ,"); 
     }
    }
        $Consulta .= $consulty;
        $Consulta .= " FROM datos_archivo WHERE estadotrabajador='".$estad."' ";
        $Consulta .= $municc;       
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Casillas</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="Post">
    <p>
      Nombre
      <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="nombre">
      <br>
Municipio
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="municipio">
      <br>
      Cargo
      <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="cargo">
      <br>
Fecha Nacimiento
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="fecha_nacimiento">
<br>
Tipo sanguineo
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="tiposanguineo">
<br>
Estado Trabajador
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="estadotrabajador" id="estados[]">
<br>
Direccion
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="direccion" id="estados[]">
<br>
Telefono
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="telefono" id="estados[]">
<br>
Email
<input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="correo" id="estados[]">
    <br>
    Sexo
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="sexo" id="estados[]">
    <br>
    Nivel Academico
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="nivelacademico" id="estados[]">
    <br>
    Identificacion
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="identificacion" id="estados[]">
    </p>
    <p>
      Solo del Municipio
      <select name="municipio" id="municipio" required>
       <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option value="COROZAL">COROZAL</option>
        <option value="PLATO">PLATO</option>
        <option value="TODOS">TODOS</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      Solos de Estado
      <select name="estadotrabajador" id="estadotrabajador" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option value="activo">Activo</option>
        <option value="inactivo">Inactivo</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      Mostrar la
      Edad
      <input name="edad" type="checkbox" id="edad" value="si">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </p>    
</form>
<br>
<?php 
//echo $Consulta; 
$sql=$Consulta;
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die (mysql_error());
$libros=array();
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
$libros[]=$rows;
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
<div class="container">
 <h2>Exportar datos a Excel con PHP y MySQL</h2>
 <div class="well-sm col-sm-12">
 <div class="btn-group pull-right">
 <form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
 <button type="submit" id="export_data" name='export_data'
value="Export to excel" class="btn btn-info">Exportar a Excel</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
 <tr>
 <th>nombre</th>
 <th>municipio</th>
 <th>edad</th>
 <th>estadotrabajador</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody>
 <?php foreach($libros as $libro) { ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $libro ['nombre']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $libro ['municipio']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $libro ['edad']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $libro ['estadotrabajador']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST["export_data"])) {
 if(!empty($libros)) {
 $filename = "libros.xls";
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
 $mostrar_columnas = false;
 foreach($libros as $libro) {
 if(!$mostrar_columnas) {
 echo implode("\t", array_keys($libro)) . "\n";
 $mostrar_columnas = true;
 }
 echo implode("\t", array_values($libro)) . "\n";
 }
 }else{
 echo 'No hay datos a exportar';
 }
 exit;
}
 ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>


creo que deberas de aprender acerca de datatables, datatables es una libreria en javascript que te permite generar tablas responsivas que ya tiene n integrado funciones para sorting y exportaciones a pdf, excel y no recuerdo que otros formatos mas. https://datatables.net

Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.

El sitio está diseñado para que publiques preguntas separadas en lugar de combinar varias preguntas en una sola publicación. Te invito a [edit] esta pregunta, dejar una sola y hacer nuevas publicaciones. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.
